# Trying to include httpclient.h inside ldebug.c is causing an error during compilation

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, firmware

My goal is to do an http post request inside ldebug.c by including httpclient. It worked in dbg_printf.c but I'm getting compilation errors in ldebug.c.

```
In file included from ../ldebug.c:28:0:
../../http/httpclient.h:69:24: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'http_request'
 void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR http_request(const char * url, const char * method, const char * headers, const char * post_data, http_callback_t callback_handle, int redirect_follow_count);
```

Is there another way I can do a post request?

Comment: It seems that `ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR` is not defined. Perhaps you need to include some other header file as well.

Comment: @lhf I included httpclient.h in dbg_printf and didn't get any errors. Why would the linker suddenly not know what ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR means?

Comment: It's not a linker error, it's a compiler error. It doesn't work in ldebug.c because the symbol ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR isn't defined in the header files that file includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR` is a macro defined in the file [c_types.h](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/sdk/include/c_types.h)

There are two reasons that it wouldn't be defined.

First, ldebug.c may not include c_types.h or include a file which #includes c_types.h. This is easy to fix - edit ldebug.c and add

```
#include <c_types.h>
```

before `#include <httpclient.h>`

The other possibility is that the symbol `ICACHE_FLASH` is not defined when ldebug.c gets compiled. The file c_types.h only defines `ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR` if `ICACHE_FLASH` is #define'd. If the first fix doesn't work, you'll need to make sure that you `#define ICACHE_FLASH` when you compile ldebug.c

The easiest way to do this is to add

```
#define ICACHE_FLASH 1
```

as the very first line of ldebug.c

Or you can make sure that you set `-DICACHE_FLASH=1` as a compiler flag in whatever your development environment is. Changing ldebug.c is almost certainly the easier way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! What ended up working was copying the entire `ICACHE_FLASH` definition from `c_types.h` into `ldebug.c`.